# How do I convert a T-SQL query to PostgreSQL that concatenates substrings?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    *,
    CONCAT(
        RIGHT( account_no, 4),
        RIGHT( customer_id, 5 )
    ) AS "password for my diplomo"
FROM
    account_info;
```

But I get this error:

> Error: function `left(bigint, integer)` does not exist;

My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE account_info (
    account_no  bigint       NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id varchar(...)
)
```

Comment: `as password for my diplomo` **what**?

Comment: The query you have shown can not generate the error "left() does not exist" as your query does not use a `left()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html) `left` and `right` expect their first argument be `text`.
So first cast `account_no` to type `text` and your query (a bit simplified) will work.

```sql
SELECT *,
       right(account_no::text, 4) || right(customer_id, 5) as pfmd
FROM account_info;
```

Unrelated but the best practice under Postgres is to use type `text` instead of `char` or `varchar`.

Comment: Hey, 
Thank you for the answer. :) This one works well

Comment: I have one more followup question, if I want to take middle three numbers from column "account_no" instead of last 4 how do I do that? Like from 3rd digit of account number to  6th digit of ACC no. totally 4 digits?

Comment: Use `substring` [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html). `substring(account_no::text from 3 for 4)`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a reference for T-SQL or JET Red SQL (for MS SQL Server and MS Access respectively) when you're actually using PostgreSQL which uses completely different functions (and syntax) for string/text processing.

[This is the PostgreSQL v12 manual page for string functions and other syntax. You should read it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html).

As for making your query run on PostgreSQL, change it to this:

- Convert `account_no` to a `varchar` type so you can use `SUBSTRING` with it.

  - I think it might work without it, but I don't like relying on implicit conversion, especially when localization/locale/culture issues might pop-up.
- The `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions for extracting substrings can be reimplemented like so:

  ```
  LEFT( text, length ) == SUBSTRING( text FROM 0 FOR length )
  RIGHT( text, length ) == SUBSTRING( text FROM CHAR_LENGTH( text ) - length )
  ```
- And use `||` to concatenate text values together.

Like so:

```
SELECT
    q.*,
    (
        SUBSTRING( q.account_no_text FROM CHAR_LENGTH( q.account_no_text ) - 4 )
        ||
        SUBSTRING( q.customer_id FROM CHAR_LENGTH( q.customer_id ) - 5 )
    ) AS "password for my diplomo"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ai.*,
            ai.account_no::varchar(10) AS account_no_text
        FROM
            account_info AS ai
    )
        AS q
```

[Here is a runnable DB-Fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8hRSLTUWNPK1t6cLGsNkzw/0)

Screenshot proof:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. :)  Happy Thanksgiving.